# sqlite3 OperationalError: no such table: main error on repl.it but not on PC

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I am making a discord bot with discord.py that relies on the sqlite3 database for storing guild info. While making the bot on my pc, everything was going great and I didn't get the error, but when I upload it to repl.it, it gives that error all of a sudden. Why does it do that?

```py
import time
import requests
import random
import asyncio
import datetime
import discord
import sqlite3
import randfacts
from discord.ext import tasks, commands


class FactsCog(commands.Cog, name = "Facts"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.fotd.start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=20.0)
    async def fotd(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT channel_id FROM main")
        channels = cursor.fetchall()
        for ID in channels:
            fact = randfacts.getFact()
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(int(ID[0]))
            embed = discord.Embed(colour = 0x4f92ff, title = "Fact Of The Day", description = fact)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/811504534177579038/820069055444156436/TriviaTops.png')
            embed.set_footer(text = "Fact Of The Day - Trivia Tops", icon_url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/811504534177579038/820069055444156436/TriviaTops.png')
            await channel.send(embed = embed)

    @fotd.before_loop
    async def before_start(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(FactsCog(bot))
    print("Facts cog loaded!")
```

This^ is my code and I'm sure that there aren't any problems as it runs on my PC just fine, but errors "sqlite3 OperationalError: no such table: main" on repl.it.

Thanks for reading, I would appreciate it if you could some how elaborate your answers more as I only started python yesterday.

Comment: Probably because the file `main.sqlite` does not exist in the repl.it environment.

Comment: @sytech That doesnt seem to be the problem because it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

the file main.sqlite does not exist in the repl.it environment. To get around this, you can use `:memory:` instead to create the database in-memory instead of using a file.

Just be warned, this also means the db will go away when the program finishes executing.

```
        db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
```